# Getting this error while trying to send mail using smtp server from java! how to solve this

Tags: java, email

So i am trying to send a pdf through mail using Gmail smtp port 465 but it keeps on throwing this error,
googled it but couldn't solve this.

i don't understand whats wrong? help me on this?

thanks in advance

tried:

1.changing ports

2.tried to correct something on certificates didn't work

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sample.pdf.PDFMailing.pdfMail(PDFMailing.java:72)
    at com.sample.pdf.GeneratePdf.addDataToPdf(GeneratePdf.java:42)
    at com.sample.pdf.Report.main(Report.java:47)
```

PDFMailing.java

```
public static void pdfMail(String file){
        //Sender email-ID and Password.
                final String senderEmail="xxxxxx";//Sender Mail ID
                final String password="xxxxx";//Sender Mail ID Password.                
                //setting the Properties.
                Properties props=new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); //SSL Port
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); //SSL Factory Class
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //Enabling SMTP Authentication
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); //SMTP Port

                //Authenticating the mailID of the sender.
                    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                        //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
                        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(senderEmail, password);
                        }
                    };

                    //Creating and getting the Session Object.
                 Session session=Session.getInstance(props, auth);

                 //Setting the From, To, Subject, MessageBody. 
                 try{
                     Message message=new MimeMessage(session);
                     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail));//Sender Mail ID
                     message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("harshapirate@gmail.com"));//Receiver Mail ID
                     message.setSubject("Sample ECO PDF file");
                     message.setText("This a Sample ECO PDF file.");

                     MimeBodyPart bodyPart=new MimeBodyPart();
                      Multipart multipart=new MimeMultipart();

                      bodyPart.setText("This is multipart Text.");


                      //Attachments for any file.
                    MimeBodyPart pdfAttachment=new MimeBodyPart();
                    pdfAttachment.attachFile(file);

                    //Attach the Body part to the Multipart.
                    multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
                    multipart.addBodyPart(pdfAttachment);

                    //Associate multipart to the message.
                    message.setContent(multipart);

                      System.out.println("Sending mail is in process.......");

                      //sending the message to-address mail.
                     Transport.send(message);
                     System.out.println("Mail has been sent sucessfully.");
                 }
                 catch(Exception e){
                     throw new RuntimeException(e);

                 }
    }
```

Comment: You might need to upgrade your Java version. Or add the newer root certificate yourself to Java's `cacerts` file.

Comment: upgraded it didn't work how to add a newer root certificate?

Comment: What did you upgrade it to?

Comment: I mean sorry i updated it sorry! @StephenC

Comment: So ... what did you update it to?

Comment: it updated to 8.0.2510.8 @StephenC

Comment: Are you using the latest JavaMail version? Currently 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I presume that is Java 8.0.251.  Since you have the latest Java 8 release then this should not be happening:

- The root certificates in a 8.0.251 keystore should all be current.
- The real smtp.google.com should be using well-known root certificates.
- The real smtp.google.com would not be presenting the cert chain in the wrong order.

So I think that something is else "getting in the way".  Likely explanations include:

- Something that is sending outgoing email connections through an SMTP proxy; e.g. a firewall or anti-virus product.
- You are running on an application server that has overridden the set of trusted certificates provided by the JDK.

It is also possible that something has subverted your DNS or IP routing and you are talking to a spoofed "smtp.gmail.com" server.

Comment: You are running on an application server that has overridden the set of trusted certificates provided by the JDK. i think this is the case because I have tomcat server on the run it may have overridden the trust certificates!

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Check if latest JDK is installed (Command: java -version) so that it has latest
  certificates and updated CA's.
- Check if there are multiple JDKs or JREs installed: If so remove them.
- Check if JAVA_HOME is pointing to the latest JDK you installed.
  (Command: echo $JAVA_HOME in linux Or echo %JAVA_HOME% in Windows command prompt)
- Check if your system date and time are correct.

If above is verified then your Java installation is fine.

Code:

- I see a missing property in your code: props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"). 
  Add it and try.

Hope you are able to access Gmail from your browser at least. This confirms that your machine is able to access Gmail servers - Though not an exact test for SMTP, but it is still good to test.

If you are running inside Tomcat, then ensure you have the latest version and hope it has its certificate store not customized or altered in some way.

If everything above is OK, then either you are behind some proxy or you are hacked.

Comment: i've checked everything and added the line you suggested!. still getting the error. I've got tomcat installed maybe it tampered the certificates?! @sugaGenius?

Comment: Any proxy or firewall or anti virus you have installed? Turn them off and try

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check for a system property or other way that someone has defined a different trust store e.g. with: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=somefilename.jks

See: https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference

But the default truststore should be $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts (but its contents vary between the Oracle JDK and OpenJDK - this was later fixed, see: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/319 )

Inspecting/modifying the contents of the store can be done with the command line tool: keytool or a GUI like: https://keystore-explorer.org/

Before you go crazy try starting your application with the following extra System Property for java (-Dsystempropertyname=value):

`-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Then you will exactly see all details of the used trust store and offered certificates from the server, details of the SSL/TLS handshake and even all data encrypted/decrypted.

For all the information there is on this subject see the JSSE Reference Guide for your Java version, e.g.: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

The same kind of code, I have written earlier and is in working state. Could you please give a try on using this code below:

Also, check the proper version of Java installed 8+ in your system, with all the Environment variables properly set and required for your project. If any proxy settings exists in your system, try to remove it and then again running the code.

```
//this will work only for gmail.

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

import com.[MyProjectRelatedImports].pojo.EmployeeDetails; 

public class SendEmail {
    public static void sendMail(List<EmployeeDetails> emplDetails) {

        Address[] to = new Address[emplDetails.size()];
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
                to[i] = new InternetAddress(emplDetails.get(i).getEmail());
            }
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String tom = "xyz@gmail.com";// address of recipient

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "abc@gmail.com"; //address of sender
// Assuming you are sending email from localhost
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "emailID"); // User name
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", "password"); // password
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");// default mail submission port
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("emailID", "password"); // username will be your email address and password same as your Gmail account.
// And if your account is protected with 2 step verification then you need to generate the app password from the link provided
//https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
            }
        });

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
// Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
// Set To: header field of the header.      //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(tom));
//Send Email to multiple recipients
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
// Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("Subject text via Java Class");
            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("Message Content should be written here!!! Regards: Pratishtha Sharma ");
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mEx){
            mEx.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```